# Removing an element from an array without using list

Tags: java, arrays

I've been trying for ages to make a method that lets me remove an item from an array by making a  new array, reducing it's size by 1, and then copying everything over except for the item in "position". Any reason why my code wouldn't be working? I can't use the list function though, I have to use arrays.

```
int newArray[] = new int[originalArray.length - 1];

for (int i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
    if (i < position)
        newArray[i] = originalArray[i];
    else if (i == position)
        i++;
    else if (i > position)
        newArray[i] = originalArray[i];
}
```

Comment: Can you show error code? I think that there is issue with trying to write out of range element. You should make `else newArray[i] = originalArray[i+1];` instead two `else if`

Comment: You're getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, yes? The stack trace tells you the line number where the error occurred. This is often a good place to start looking. In this case, focus on your final `else if`. The code is writing the element to the same position in the new array that it was in the old array... but the arrays are not the same length, and there's nowhere to put the last element from the original array.

Comment: @dnault I'm getting no errors, just nothing is getting removed

Comment: The program doesn't stop running, it keeps going, just nothing gets removed from the arrays

Comment: I JUST REALISED IT WAS BECAUSE WHEN I CALLED THE METHOD, I WASN'T OVERWRITING A STRING!

Comment: i feel so dumb sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int[] removeElement(int[] originalArray, int position) {
    int newArray[] = new int[originalArray.length - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
        if (i < position)
            newArray[i] = originalArray[i];
        else if (i > position)
            newArray[i - 1] = originalArray[i];
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

***P.S.** I reccomend you to use `System.arraycopy()`:*

```
public static int[] removeElement(int[] arr, int pos) {
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= arr.length)
        return arr;
    if (arr.length == 1)
        return new int[0];

    int[] res = new int[arr.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, res, 0, pos);
    System.arraycopy(arr, pos + 1, res, pos, arr.length - pos - 1);
    return res;
}
```

**Output:**

```
int[] arr = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int[] res = removeElement(arr, 4);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));   // [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I'm going to try this out, thank you!

Comment: Still not working :( When I'm deleting it, this is the code I'm using ```System.out.println("Please enter the number of the position of the item that you would like to remove");
     
     int remove1 = 0;
     
     remove1 = myInput.nextInt();
     
     Array.removeStringElement(cartList, remove1);
     Array.removeElement(cartQuantity, remove1);
     Array.removeElement(cartTotal, remove1);
     Array.removeElement(cartTotal1, remove1);

Comment: Could something be wrong with that part?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to write element out of range, try this:

```
int newArray[] = new int[originalArray.length - 1];

for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    if (i < position)
        newArray[i] = originalArray[i];
    else
        newArray[i] = originalArray[i+1];
}
```